# How to reverse a queue and display it

Tags: c++, class, queue, reverse

I have made a queue class and I have a queue and I want to reverse it,however when I implement the function it doesn't display anything.
Here's it

```
void reverse(Queue <T> &queue) {
    if(!queue.empty())
    {
        int temp=queue.queue_front;
        queue.pop(queue.queue_front);
        reverse(queue);
        queue.push(temp);
    }
}
```

The pop function I'm using requires a value,that's why there is queue.queue_front.I'm trying to do it with a recursion.Here's my print function

```
void display() {
    for(int current = queue_front+1; current < queue_length; current++)
    {
         cout << "[" << current << "]=" << queue_array [current] << " ";
    }
}
```

Now that's what I'm doing in the main function

```
Queue <int>queue1(10);
queue1.push(16);
queue1.push(14);
queue1.push(6);
queue1.push(60);
queue1.reverse(queue1);
queue1.display();
```

Here's the pop function

```
void pop(T& item) {
    if (empty()) {
        cout << "The Queue is empty!";
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        queue_front = (queue_front + 1) % queue_size; 
        item = queue_array[queue_front];
        queue_length--;
    }
}
```

It doesn't display anything.Thanks.

Comment: The reverse doesn't have to be with recursion so any method will work.

Comment: temp should be T, not int as you take a Queue of T. I don't see any problems with the reverse function. `int current = queue_front+1` seems wrong, but as you haven't shown the implementation of Queue, it might not be. I don't like the interface of pop and reverse, as they are member functions, and shouldn't need the Queue passed in.

Comment: Does the display work without reversing it?

Comment: Yeah,without the reverse it works.I also prefer without passing a value to pop but in this case that's how it has to be.Also I'm making current=queue_front+1 because when it's just =queue_front it starts from -1,because that's the default value for queue_front.

Comment: Just did it,hope that helps

Comment: Could you paste the entire program in one file that I can compile and run please?

Answer (score 0):

You're testing with a queue of integers, which hides quite a few bugs.
You should have tested with a `Queue<std::string>`.

First, here:

```
int temp=queue.queue_front;
```

you're saving an index, not an element.
What you intend must be

```
T temp = queue.queue_array[queue.queue_front];
```

but there's no reason to mess with member variables (see below).

Here,

```
queue.pop(queue.queue_front);
```

you're passing a reference to the queue's member to `pop`.
The parameter to `pop` is where the top element is stored after it's popped.

In other words, after that line, `queue.queue_front` will be the *element* that was at the front of the queue, not the index of the new front of the queue.

This would probably work:

```
void reverse(Queue <T> &queue) {
    if(!queue.empty())
    {
        T temp;
        queue.pop(temp);
        reverse(queue);
        queue.push(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: It runs,however it still doesn't display anything.Wonder what could the reason be,the recursion and the display function seem to be right.

Comment: @ander You need to worry about `% queue_size` in the display function too, since the queue "wraps around" the array. Also, test with a queue with only one element first, then expand your test case. (Have you really tested `pop` in isolation? The order of operations looks weird.)

Comment: The recursion doesn't display with one element too,the pop function I'm not sure if it works properly- when I have three elemets and pop one then it just shows the second one and doesn't the third one.Also the indexation doesn't change-the [1] elements stays [1].